# React app is showing blank page on the localhost after running. I have checked everything but can't find a fault

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

React app is showing a blank page when I run it on localhost.

This is my code for app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Footer, Blog, Possibility, Features, WhatGPT3, Header} from './containers';
import {Navbar, Brand, CTA} from './components';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="gradient_bg">
                <Navbar />
                <Header />

            </div>
            <Brand />
            <WhatGPT3 />
            <Features />
            <Possibility />
            <CTA />
            <Blog />
            <Footer />
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

this is my code for index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and this is my index.html file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Help me out please.

The output should've been a very simple output like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxE6m.png)

but its showing a blank page,no errors.

Comment: Could you please attache the browser console with a screenshot?

Comment: I checked the attached image that shows the result. It seems it works. I recommend you check the CSS and mentioned components. So that all components has all needed functions and UI.